# What is ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING used for in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions, analytic-functions

I am just starting on Teradata and I have come across an Ordered Analytical Function called "Rows unbounded preceding" in Teradata. I tried several sites to learn about the function but all of them uses a complicated example explaining the same. 
Could you please provide me with a naive example so that I can get the basics clear?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It's the "frame" or "range" clause of window functions, which are part of the SQL standard and implemented in many databases, including Teradata.

A simple example would be to calculate the average amount in a frame of three days. I'm using PostgreSQL syntax for the example, but it will be the same for Teradata:

```sql
WITH data (t, a) AS (
  VALUES(1, 1),
        (2, 5),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 5),
        (5, 4),
        (6, 11)
)
SELECT t, a, avg(a) OVER (ORDER BY t ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
FROM data
ORDER BY t
```

... which yields:

```
t  a  avg
----------
1  1  3.00
2  5  3.00
3  3  4.33
4  5  4.00
5  4  6.67
6 11  7.50
```

As you can see, each average is calculated *"over"* an ordered frame consisting of the range between the previous row (`1 preceding`) and the subsequent row (`1 following`).

When you write `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, then the frame's lower bound is simply infinite. This is useful when calculating sums (i.e. ["running totals"](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/04/29/nosql-no-sql-how-to-calculate-running-totals/)), for instance:

```sql
WITH data (t, a) AS (
  VALUES(1, 1),
        (2, 5),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 5),
        (5, 4),
        (6, 11)
)
SELECT t, a, sum(a) OVER (ORDER BY t ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM data
ORDER BY t
```

yielding...

```
t  a  sum
---------
1  1    1
2  5    6
3  3    9
4  5   14
5  4   18
6 11   29
```

[Here's another very good explanations of SQL window functions](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/20-Window-Functions).

Answer (score 101):

`ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is no Teradata-specific syntax, it's Standard SQL. Together with the `ORDER BY` it defines the window on which the result is calculated.

Logically a Windowed Aggregate Function is newly calculated for each row within the PARTITION based on all ROWS between a starting row and an
ending row.

Starting and ending rows might be fixed or relative to the
current row based on the following keywords:

- CURRENT ROW, the current row
- UNBOUNDED PRECEDING, all rows before the current row -> fixed
- UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING, all rows after the current row -> fixed
- x PRECEDING, x rows before the current row -> relative
- y FOLLOWING, y rows after the current row -> relative

Possible kinds of calculation include:

- Both starting and ending row are fixed, the window consists of all rows of a partition, e.g. a Group Sum, i.e. aggregate plus detail rows
- One end is fixed, the other relative to current row, the number of rows increases or decreases, e.g. a Running Total, Remaining Sum
- Starting and ending row are relative to current row, the number of rows within a window is fixed, e.g. a Moving Average over *n* rows

So `SUM(x) OVER (ORDER BY col ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` results in a *Cumulative Sum* or *Running Total*

```
11 -> 11
 2 -> 11 +  2                = 13
 3 -> 13 +  3 (or 11+2+3)    = 16
44 -> 16 + 44 (or 11+2+3+44) = 60
```