# SQL create dense rank based on mulitple columns

Tags: sql, teradata, rank, dense-rank

I have a data set with two fields in which I need to create a dense rank for. When Field_1 is not null then Field_2 is null and vice-versa.

```
Field_1 Field_2
a   
        1
        2
        3
        4
b   
        7
        8
        9
c   
        15
        20
        25
```

Im trying to get to this

```
Field_1 Field_2 Field_3
a               1
        1       1
        2       1
        3       1
        4       1
b               2
        7       2
        8       2
        9       2
c               3
        15      3
        20      3
        25      3
```

I can order the data wit the following line:

```
row_number() over (partition by null order by Field_2,Field_1) as Field_3
```

but this does not give me the dense rank I am looking for.

Comment: Without any extra columns, how are we supposed to know that `1`-`4` are supposed to belong to the same group as `a`?

Comment: Sigh..it's a rough data set.  The data provided is an example but the `row_number` I provided is how the data is ordered.  It is sequential. I was hoping to formulate a query to fill in the blanks in Field_1 but I do not want to do a recursive query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do have some sort of incremental row number column (we'll call it `row_number`), you can use a windowing clause to count the number of populated `field_1` values:

```
COUNT(field_1) OVER (ORDER BY row_number ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS group_number
```

This makes it where each row counts the number of populated `field_1` values that come *before* it (including itself) when ordered by `row_number`.

Here's some more details on the technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30862368/477563

Comment: thanks that worked! I used 'Field_3' from my post as the `row_number`

Comment: I also came up with a different way a well but is more complicated. `select
qry1.Field_1
,qry1.Field_2
,Cast(Sum(qry1.Field_1_Binary) over (Partition By null Order By qry1.Field_3  Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row) as Float) as Rank_Field
from
(
Select
Field_1
,Field_2
,row_number() over (partition by null order by Field_2,Field_1) as Field_3
,case when Field_1 = null then 1 else 0 end as Field_1_Binary
) as qry1`